# Python defaultdict list numbering

Tags: python, enumerate

I have this code where I fill a defaultdict list through an incrementing loop, however the problem is the output. I was a list that contains the values that are read in only and not enumerated positions as I have to write it out to a CSV file. This is the loop to fill the list

```
m = defaultdict(list)
for j in range (0, len(names)):
with open(names[j]) as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
            columns[i].append(v)
    m[j]=max(columns[1], key=float)
```

my problem is the output which is shown here

```
 (0, '1.8768e-02'), (1, '2.4838e-02'), (2, '3.4145e-02'), (3,  '4.6328e-02'), (4, '5.3245e-02'), (5, '6.0994e-02'), (6, '5.7532e-02'), (7, '6.2890e-02'), (8, '6.6898e-02'), (9, '8.2745e-02'), (10, '5.8015e-02')
```

How could I edit the code to only allow the value to be stored and not enumerate the max value of each file?

Comment: columns is a defaultdict list that  reads in the values of a full column and allows the program to find the max value of that column

Comment: it is the output of m

Comment: Is this the output of `m.items()`? If so, this is perfectly normal! The numbers `1`, `2`, etc. are the keys, i.e. `j`, the number of the file, not `i`, the number of the row generated by `enumerate`.

Comment: But is it possible to write this to the csv file without having these numbers written also? as it doesnt seem to be doing this with just writer.writerow(m)

Comment: Why are you using a `defaultdict` at all? It seems you could just make `m` an ordinary list and just append to that list. Also, please show more code, so we don't have to guess as much!

Comment: Thanks, changing it to an ordinary list did the job, thank you Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you are doing there. As I gather from your code and comments, your are collecting values from a number of CSV files in the `defaultdict m` and then write those to another CSV file.

You seem to do this with `writer.writerow(m.items())`. This way, the CSV file will include the keys from the dict, as that is exactly what [`items`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns: A list of all the `(key, value)` pairs from the dictionary. If you want to have just the values, you can use `m.values()`. Note that those values are not guaranteed to be ordered, but in your case it seems to work, as the keys are just increasing numbers. To make sure, you could sort the items and take just the value:

```
writer.writerow([v for (k,v) in sorted(m.items())])
```

However, this also means that you do not need a dictionary at all, much less a `defaultdict`. Just use a plain-old list to collect those values and write that list to the file.

```
m = []
# in your read-block:
    m.append(max(columns[1], key=float))
# in your write block:
    writer.writerow(m)
```